# LM317 Voltage of 1.8v

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, gps

I want to get 1.8v to power a gps unit, from the 5 volt pin of an Arduino.

What do I need to change on this schematic to achieve that voltage?

[image]

Comment: Have you read the data sheet?

Comment: Why not just use a fixed 1.8V regulator?

Comment: @OlinLathrop -- likely because he doesn't have any 1.8V fixed regs handy (I certainly don't!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have R1 as a 500Ω resistor and R2 as a 220Ω resistor.

That should give you 1.7999999999999998 volts.

Comment: +1 for the calc.  But it'd be more useful if it had a list of standard value resistors, you put in a voltage and a percentage tolerance and it gave you all pairs of standard resistance within a given tolerance of your voltage.

Comment: Yeah, that's functionality I have been meaning to add.  Shouldn't be too hard to arrange.  It served my purposes at the time though ;)

Comment: Your calculator is some kind of faulty: 1.25*(1+(500/220)) is 1.8, not 1.799999.... 
Adding the Iref error: around 1.822V

Comment: 220Ω (or 240Ω) across Vout/Adj is not okay with LM317. It's just a very well estabilished misconception. *Minimun output current to mantein regulation* is 10mA for LM317 and this calls for R1=120Ω. That picture with 240Ω is an LM**1**17 application, which is okay with load above 5mA.

Comment: 18 digit accuracy in this case is absurd.  We do engineering here, which includes using significant digits properly. -1.

Comment: Oh and here come the pedants crawling out of the woodwork. Come on, boys, you're only 5 years late.

Comment: @olin who gives a flying monkey's but how many significant digits there are? No one except you. Stop posting anally retentive pointless comments and do something useful with your life.

Comment: Significant digits matter.  In science and engineering they are expected to be used properly.  By using so many fraction digits, you are saying the voltage is way more accurate than it could ever be.  That's just plain wrong.

Comment: @olin I just say it how it is. If you can't cope with more than 2 numbers in a row then you should go back to school.

Comment: The point is you're NOT saying how it is.  "1.7999999999999998 volts" means the value is good to somewhere around 10^-16 volts, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: That depends on your resistors. With mine it is good to that resolution. They are made of unobtanium.

Comment: R1 resistor value is too high. Refer to datasheet.

Answer (score 6):

For the LM317, Vout = 1.25(1 + R2/R1)

Using R1 = 220 ohms and R2 = 100 ohms, Vout will be 1.82 volts

Comment: What is the difference between the two capacitors in the schematic?

Comment: Well the capacitors aren't exactly needed, the output capacitor is optional and it helps improve the transient response. the datasheet always helps :)
http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM117.pdf

Comment: The 0.1 uF cap C1 is a bypass for the input, and needed if the LM317 is more than 6 inches from the filter caps on the DC supply used as the input source.  The 1 uF cap C2 filters transients on the output.  You can use any value from 1 uF up to 1000 uF for additional filtering.

Comment: +1 for not abusing significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

Right values:

R1 = 390 Ω
R2 = 172 Ω
Vout = 1.25 V (1 + 172 Ω / 390 Ω) = 1.8012 V
Vout = ~1.8 V